# Nextpeer Unity Game Crashes on Nextpeer.LaunchDashboard();

Tags: crash, unity-game-engine, nextpeer

I have integrated the latest plugin, and followed the tutorial step by step. 
When I call the Nextpeer.LaunchDashboard(); method the screen goes black and in some seconds I get the info that application has stopped working. Any clues? I am running Unity 4,3 and my device is Samsung Galaxy s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documenting the answer for posterity. The crash was reported as:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nextpeer.android.R$style

This happened because the package name in Nextpeer's AndroidManifest.xml (Assets/Plugins/Android/Nextpeer/AndroidManifest.xml) was changed (to the game's package name, in this case). Reverting the package name back to `com.nextpeer.android` solved the issue.

Comment: This Indeed helped. I can now continue implementing this amazing  Nextpeer plugin. It is worth to mention that the customer support in Nextpeer is simply amazing. Thanks